# PhpStorm adds ^M on each new line (Windows)

Tags: windows, phpstorm

I just downloaded a new project on my Windows machine, every time I add a new line anywhere, it adds a `^M` character:

Add a new line to code:

```
   public function loginAction( Request $request )
   {

       return;
   }
```

git diff :

```
   public function loginAction( Request $request )
   {
+^M
      return;
   }
```

How do I get rid of the `^M` sign? I didn't have this problem until I recently reinstalled my OS (from win10 to win10).

What I tried so far:

- Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> Line separator -> Unix and OS X (\n).
- Installed Webmaster  plugin (found this from the one answer on google).

Comment: No idea. What other custom plugins do you have? What `idea.log` has to say (Help | Show Log in ...)?

Comment: @LazyOne its a fresh phpstorm install, no plugins, default settings.

Comment: Does it also show you LF in the status bar?
http://prntscr.com/j1q41j